# Why Google reverse geocoding stops working if I add data to Firestore - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reverse-geocoding

I use reverseGeocoding on server-side hosted by Firebase.

If I want to add data to Firestore right after receiving a response from reverseGeocode, it's not working anymore. Code is ignored and no error is thrown.

```js
googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({
    latlng: [-33.8571965, 151.2151398],
})
.asPromise()
.then((response) => {
    if (response.json.status != "OK") {
        console.log('Geocode error');
    }else {
        console.log("Geocode OK");

        var db = admin.firestore();
        var docRef = db.collection('medias').doc('Sydney Opera House');

        console.log(docRef);

        docRef.set({
            test: "value stored"
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR - GEOCODE", err);
});
```

If I remove

```js
docRef.set({
    test: "value stored"
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I get "Geocode OK" and the *docRef* value in my log. Otherwise nothing! Nothing is stored and no error is thrown!

I don't get why just because I try to set data inside my Firestore reference, it f*cked up everything!!!

**UPDATE**

I realised that if I intentionally create an error for the function to catch it, then the next lines are well executed.

For example, if I add `dumbFunction();` just before `var db = ...` then it catches the error `ERROR - GEOCODE ReferenceError: dumbFunction is not defined` but the function is still well executed.

How?

Comment: You aren't seeing an error because you aren't logging any. Include a `catch` at the end of your _set_ command to see why the set is failing, like this: `docRef.set({
    location: {
        latlng: location_latlng
    }
}).catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: @JeremyW , already tried, I still don't get any error. - but I updated my code above with 'catch' and simplified the code to remove all useless lines. I really don't understand

Comment: You've done a good job showing the relevant code, there's nothing different from the docs except for your `var db = ` line. In [the Firestore docs for NodeJS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) it defines `db` as: `var db = admin.firestore();` and you're calling .firestore() from `appServer` instead of `admin`... what is the `appServer` you have?

Comment: @JeremyW , I'm initialising it with `var admin = require("firebase-admin"); var appServer = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` because the code is on the server side (at the very beginning of my js file). Look at my last edit. If I initialise it twice, I get an error but it's working.

Comment: @JeremyW , added a last update. Very weird

Comment: That's really weird behavior... hmmm.... I have no clue

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with stripe's api for creating a customer. Did you figure out what is going on?

Comment: @Jamesm131 No. I do what I need on the client side instead

Comment: @Cedric Hmm I'm not sure what the issue is. I created another cloud function with a http trigger and called that in place of the firestore code. That worked without any problems, though it does add an extra function call.